# Weird min API level for AndroidHttpClient

Tags: android

I was messing with my DataDroid library and the new lint check revealed a weird bug in the Android SDK.

For those who don't know DataDroid, it's a library for local and remote data management (more info available here : http://datadroid.foxykeep.com)

To call webservices in the library, I use the class AndroidHttpClient to make the connection to the server in my NetworkConnection class. My library is available for Android 1.6 and higher version and I never had any problem with it even on 1.6 phones.

What's weird is that in the SDK documentation, we can see that [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) is available only for API 2.2 and higher. I discovered that via the new lint check "NewApi" which showed an error saying that the minSdkVersion was not high enough.

I looked at the source code of Android and I found out that this class existed already in 1.6 and was not private. So I think there is a bug in the min API level of this class in the documentation... it should be 4 (maybe lower but I didn't check)

The only problem is I don't know where this information is stored, so I can't create a patch to fix it...

Comment: This isn't really a solution, but if you know for sure it works and just want the error to go away, the new ADT provides an annotation to suppress the check by putting, in your case, @TargetApi(8) in the class(es) giving you the error.

Comment: @Foxykeep Could you give me the link of android 1.6 source code has existed AndroidHttpClient? I have checked but can't see anything.

Comment: @alexc : It's a solution I used for my project but other people may have the same problem as me for their own project... fixing the sdk would be better :)

Comment: @r4j : I cloned the Android git repo from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base and switched my branch to the eclair then to the donut release ones and the class is still there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class has been there for a while, but since it was not public, certain builds may exclude it and your program might fail on those. This is not a bug, there are other classes that are not hidden, but for one reason or another have not been made public (yet).

Comment: According to the [change history](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commits/master/core/java/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.java), @hide was removed since [Feb 25, 2010 - Re-arrange android-common so framework no longer links with it](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/2269d1572e5fcfb725ea55f5764d8c3280d69f6d).

Comment: OK so it was hidden but still available in most SDKs. Then I'll change it so that it use something else for API below 8